# Symmetry of the problem in using the group of rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: spectral-theory

In [Spectral Geometry in Non-standard Domains](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/14-15/summer-research14/mini-conf/SpectralGeometryReport.pdf) page $37$ point ($2$), it discusses of the symmetry of the problem in using the group of rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with certain properties. Could anyone be able to explain to me why this point is important at the resolution of the spectrum on $\mathbb{S}^2$

Comment: Why, the group of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is also the group of rotations of $\mathbb{S}^2$, isn't it?

Comment: Because we can restrain our domain on $\mathbb{S}^2$, but how that information could help me?